Rescue funds from Safe contract address that were sent on wrong Network
The title says it all. I created a multi-sig safe on Ethereum mainnet, a while ago. I sent some funds to that address on Optimism mainnet, considered it lost, since the nonce difference wouldn't allow me to get the same address. But I saw a blog suggesting a rescue method in which I basically copied on the hex data from the transaction of contract creation of safe contract on Ethereum mainnet and send a txn to GnosisSafeProxy with the same hexData. Fortunately Now the address on Optimism can be interacted with read and write as proxy on etherscan. It's visible on Safe UI as well but it doesn't allow me to send transaction from the UI. It's says in the instruction to use safe-cli, but I'm not sure how exactly can I sign from multiple private keys on Safe-cli, or create a transaction to rescue funds from the multisig. Multi-sig has 2/6 threshold for signatures. Can someone help me with cli instructions or if there is any other way to rescue funds?

Hey you can find detailed instructions as my previous answer to this question: ETH address under OP Network
Hope it helps; Best, Louis

Thank you so much, it worked like a charm.
